# Use a list of words to grep in an other list

Tags: bash, grep

I've got a list with 250 lines in it. I have to run all of them through a web server to get a list of output. This list, however returns many more lines, than I'm interested in. Say, my `list.txt` is:

```
a.1
b.1
etc
```

then the output is `output.txt`:

```
a.1 a b c
a.2 b a b
a.3 d k o
b.1 b o p
b.2 o i y
b.3 p i y
etc
```

Is it possible to use the grep command to search for all words in list.txt in the output.txt and then generate "the wanted" list wanted.txt? I need the  entire line in my output.txt
I'm new in scripting, but what I'd like is something such as

```
grep list.txt output.txt > wanted.txt
```

I haven't been able to find any examples of this

Comment: Are they both in alphabetical order like your examples?

Comment: No, I have a specific non-alphabetical order in my list.txt, but the output.txt is alphabetical, but I'd like it to contain only the "hits" for my list.txt in the same non-alphabetical order

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd ignore `grep` for this one. It's good for regular expressions but it doesn't look like you really need that here. `comm` can compare two files and show you intersections. Using your exact examples:

```
$ comm -12 list.txt output.txt 
a.1
b.1
etc
```

- `-1` suppresses lines unique to the first file
- `-2` suppresses lines unique to the second file
- `-3` suppresses lines common to both
- To get just the common lines, we suppress the unique lines, hence `-12`

This is faster than any grep will be but it relies (heavily) on the files being sorted. If they aren't, you can pre-sort them but that will alter the output so it's sorted too.

```
comm -12 <(sort list.txt) <(sort output.txt)
```

---

Alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863387) from [iiSeymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066031/iiseymour) will let you do it with `grep`. The flags ask for an input file and force a fixed-string, full-word search. This won't rely on order but will be based on the `output.txt` order. Reverse the files if you want them in the order of the list.txt.

```
$ grep -wFf list.txt output.txt 
a.1
b.1
etc
```

---

If your `list.txt` is *really* big, you might have to tackle this a little more iteratively and pass each line to grep separately. This will massively increase processing time. In the above you'd be reading `output.txt` once, but this way you'd read and process it for every list.txt line. It's horrible... But it might be your only choice. On the upside, it does then sort things by the `list.txt` order.

```
$ while read line; do grep -wF "$line" output.txt; done < list.txt
a.1
b.1
etc
```

Comment: That is really smart! What is the reason for the -12?

Comment: `-1` suppresses lines unique to the first file, `-2` suppresses lines unique to the second file, and `-3` suppresses lines common to both.  To get just the common lines, we suppress the uniques, hence `-12`.

Comment: nice! I think I'll use the comm command. And then when I want to sort the output.txt to have the same order as list.txt, I'll just use the comm -12 <(sort list.txt) <(sort output.txt) afterwards?

Comment: The comm command didn't give me the entire line in the result.txt (and I need it all to get the info from there). But if I try the grep command it promts me with grep: out of memory. Does that mean, it's too big?

Comment: the 2nd example has a redundant STDIN redirect the shell would flag as an error. either make temp files or use an extra fd with a background sort pipelined to it (tricky in most shells) ... this is more of a programming question better asked on [so]. personally, i'd be doing this in python.

Comment: Hmmm... Seems like I'm in deep water here, then. How do I make temp files? I only know to make a new file eg $ grep -wFf list.txt output.txt > wanted.txt

Comment: `sort <list.txt >/tmp/a.txt`

Comment: So I'd have to make a temp file for my list.txt that I want to search with?

Comment: be sure to remove the temp files when done unless you want the system to do it in it's typically daily cleanup

Comment: probably best to ask about how to program this in [so].

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you so much both of you to take the time to help me :)

Comment: @Skaperen I don't understand what's wrong with the second example. It's not a redundant redirect and no error is generated when I run it here. I'm processing the input files with `sort` and capturing the output and presenting it to `comm` as a file descriptor (because it needs files).

Comment: I've added a line-by-line approach. It won't be as fast as loading all the searches into memory (as the grep will) but it should also be able to work on a near infinitely long input list, albeit super-slowly. Buying more RAM might be a saner choice.